# Cannot uninstall rvm using implode command

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I am trying to uninstall rvm on mac, when I type the command `rvm implode` nothing happens, it doesn't display the message  `Are you SURE you wish for rvm to implode?`
It just displays `Psychologist intervened, cancelling implosion, crisis avoided :)`

When I searched I found that this message is displayed when you cancel the implode, the point is I am not getting a chance to cancel it, I just type `rvm implode` then enter and I get this message.

Is there something wrong in what I am doing here?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I just ran into this problem as well, use :

```
rvm implode --force
Are you SURE you wish for rvm to implode?
This will recursively remove /home/rubyadm/.rvm and other rvm traces?
```